# How to include empty archives in sitemap?

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

I am using free Yoast plugin and I see that the sitemap not include empty archives, 
 I dont see any setting related to that. 
Is there any option to make empty archives included in the sitemap? 
I don't mind changing plugins 
I want the search enginge to still scan these pages. 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This could potentially be damaging to your SEO which is why Yoast excludes it.  Either way, you'll have to open a ticket with Yoast and ask them directly.

Comment: i dont care to use other plugin, just to know how to do that

Comment: I didn't tell you to use another plugin - you said you were using a Yoast, a plugin, and I recommended opening a ticket with their support team.  Third-Party plugin questions are off topic because WPSE is intended to be WordPress Core development questions.  Why not just write code to make your own sitemap?